# Use different profile for a specific Terminal

Tags: terminal

When logging into remote server with Terminal, I need to use different profile. Is there any way to make the Terminal displayed with different profile? Better still, is there a way to recognize the login access to display with different profile automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "Profile" I assume you mean the different profiles defined in the Terminal preferences under "Settings"?

If so, modify, duplicate, or create whatever profile you want to use when connecting to the remote server. Under the "Shell" tab of the profile, set the command to run to be whatever `ssh` command you give to log into the remote server. Uncheck the "Run inside shell". Now, whenever you open that profile under the "Shell" menu of Terminal, it will launch the remote connection. If you want even more automation, assign a keyboard shortcut for that profile in the Keyboard preferences of System Preferences.

[image: Remote SSH Command in Terminal Profile]

---

If you are looking to have this happen when you *type* an `ssh` command, there are two alternatives:

1. Write a shell function to execute an osascript (AppleScript) prior to the ssh command (see [this other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63970/is-there-an-escape-sequence-that-will-change-the-background-color-in-terminal)).
2. Use something like `tput setab <n>; clear` in your remote .bashrc file. See [background coloring](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes#background_coloring) for values to use for `n`. Note that this will not persist if you embed escape codes in your prompt that reset colors or if you do something else that resets terminal colors. This will also linger after logging out, but that can be fixed with similar escape codes. It's not really changing the "Profile", but you might get the effect you are looking for.