# Terminal: how to get multiple independent different window bg colors?

Tags: terminal, preferences

Here's an obscure one, it used to be that if you ...

- opened a window A (say, green bg, your default)
- open another window B
- open prefs
- change the bg color in prefs to yellow
- that would change B to yellow, but leave the other one green

In this way you could fairly easily have mulitiple Terminal windows, with, different bg colors for clarity.

Unfortunately Apple fixed this bug a couple yrs ago!  Changing color in prefs now **changes all open windows**!

Is there any way to get different color backgrounds in Terminal when more than one window is open?

[image]

(Do note, you can set that BACKGROUND windows have low alpha (look at, strangely, the bottom of the color pane.  This doesn't help at all.  If I have four shells to four servers, I want them to have red, green, blue, yellow backgrounds. Thanks!)

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63970/is-there-an-escape-sequence-that-will-change-the-background-color-in-terminal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should make four shell profiles by using the duplicate option and create your shells from those different profiles.

Edit: There are other answers with alternatives that may better suit different use cases. This way is still going to be the nicest approach for consistent re-use of color sets.

[image]

Comment: Ah!  Spectacular - I had no idea at all about that menu option.  Thanks so much.  Bounty en route

Answer (score 7):

Ah!  Terminal now includes this:

[image]

That menu option alone DOES offer "individual" background color change.  Phew.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can still use Command-I and use that floating info panel to change the theme of any terminal window.

Comment: In fact, see my answer, it now seems to be "option-command-I" !  Great stuff.